# Is there a kqueue()/kevent() equivalent to select()'s "errorfds" set?

Tags: select, error-handling, kqueue

I was porting some code from select() to kqueue() today, and I noticed that kevent() doesn't seem to have an analog for select()'s "exception-set" feature.

That is to say, select()'s function-signature is:

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *restrict readfds, fd_set *restrict writefds, fd_set *restrict errorfds, struct timeval *restrict timeout);
```

... and with kevent(), EVFILT_READ corresponds to (readfds), and EVFILT_WRITE corresponds to (writefds), but I don't see anything like EVFILT_ERROR that would correspond to (errorfds).

Is there really just no support for socket-error-conditions under kevent(), or is it there but implemented in some way that isn't obvious to me?

Comment: What do you need errorfds for? Read errors are already reported through read events, and write errors are through write events (by the resulting read or write failing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to filter in that way. You must manually classify incoming events based on flags (EV_EOF) and fflags.